# Can a permanently anthropomorphic animal companion take levels in an NPC or PC class?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, npc, class, animal-companions

I used my Druid power to turn my animal into an anthropomorphic one, and a spell of permanency to make it permanent. Is it possible for my animal take levels in an NPC or PC class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Animal companions advance only as animal companions; NPCs (including former animal companions that are permanently anthropomorphic) gain levels only by GM decree

A [druid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid)'s [animal companion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid#TOC-Nature-Bond-Ex-) advances **only** as an [animal companion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions). An animal companion that's the target of the spell [*anthropomorphic animal*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/anthropomorphic-animal) advances as an animal companion. (The spell doesn't change the creature's type, and the rules for animal companions with Intelligence scores greater than 2 can be found [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions#TOC-Intelligent-Animals1).) So far as I am aware, [only PCs gain XP](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement) and, therefore, class levels: "As **player characters** overcome challenges, they gain experience points" (emphasis mine). Once introduced into the campaign, NPCs' levels and Hit Dice are fixed unless the GM intervenes. (Although some options—like the spell [*awaken*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/awaken)—*are* available to player-characters for mucking about with NPCs , these are rare.)

A former animal companion who's been the victim of the spell *anthropomorphic animal* and the spell [*permanency*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/permanency) would be, with the GM's permission, an interesting choice as a druid's cohort gained from the feat [Leadership](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/leadership---final), although the looming threat of reversion due to an errant [*dispel magic*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic) can't be ignored.

You can read more about anthropomorphic animal companions in Paizo messageboards threads from [2011](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2n00x?Anthropomorphic-Animal-Companion) and [2012](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2omq3?Anthropomorphic-Animal-Companions-is-it).

Comment: I like your choice of the word victim :p. Also, does Dispel Magic effect Permanency? According to the description, it only counters *ongoing* effects and permanency doesn't have a duration. It does suppress the abilities of magical items, so perhaps it would temporarily revert the companion, on GM fiat...?

Comment: @Jason_c_o The spell *permanency* has a [duration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Duration) of permanent, making it vulnerable to the spell *dispel magic*.

Comment: Huh... Not very permanent if all it takes is a dispel magic to get rid of it haha

Answer (score 2):

They don't need to be anthropomorphic.  There's no minimum attribute requirement for any class in Pathfinder, nor any prerequisite for thumbs.  Levelling in this case should be handled however your DM normally handles NPC levelling, which varies widely from group to group.  In *some* games only people who are human enough can take class levels, and in these games the difference due to the spell may make such levelling possible where it previously wasn't.  I object to that explanation on the grounds that it perpetuates an oppressive discourse, however, and suggest strongly that you find another one; either allowing levelling before the spell as well or not allowing it afterwards either.